# Why is benzoic acid less soluble in water than acetanilide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, aromatic-compounds, aniline

Why should acetanilide be more soluble in water than benzoic acid when benzoic acid has the same number of h-bonding sites and has an ionizable site, allowing it to form ion-dipole forces while acetanilide can't be ionized? I don't see how the dipoles would be significantly different as to make acetanilide more soluble. They are of the approximately same size so dispersion can't be a factor either.

Comment: The acid dimer is much less polar than the monomer.

Comment: You compare what is in solution, but not what happens in solid.

Comment: @poutnik are you sure that benzoic acid dimerizes in water?

Comment: @sweetandtangy I have not said that. What I have meant is, it could have been more soluble, if it had not formed dimers in solid.